# How do a turn a list of dataframe to into just one dataframe to download into a CSV?

Tags: python, database, list, csv, dataframe

I was able to get a dataset but it made each row of data into just a value and listed it into a data frame.

it looks like this

```
Index   Value
 0      Column Names: Name Salary Age City
 1      Column Names: Name Salary Age City
```

and those data frames include vales include

```
      Name Salary Age City
 0   Sam  52,000  42  NYC


      Name Salary Age City
 0   Mike 45,000  54  NYC
```

Note I am using spyder so when I click on the dataframe of the shows two new columns and valises for the dataframe.

My goal is to have a simple

```
    Name Salary Age City
0   Mike 45,000  54  NYC
1   Sam  52,000  42  NYC
```

where I can then put into a csv file

Comment: [Edit] your question and show **how** do you ***"get a dataset"***?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and replace dummy data with your actual dataframes you would like to join.

```
dummy_data1 = {
    'Name': ['1', '2', '6', '7', '8'],
    'Salary': ['K', 'M', 'O', 'Q', 'S'],
    'Age': ['L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T'],
    'City': ['L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data1, columns = ['Name', ' Salary', ' Age', 'City'])

dummy_data2 = {
        'Name': ['1', '2', '6', '7', '8'],
        'Salary': ['K', 'M', 'O', 'Q', 'S'],
        'Age': ['L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T'],
        'City': ['L', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'T']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data2, columns = ['Name', ' Salary', ' Age', 'City'])

print(pd.concat([df1, df2]))
```

Comment: nvm got it. Deleted my previous comment. It was just a simple df1=pd.concat(df, ignore_index=True).